# Set a max value for increasing margin when moving a div on button click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, margin

I have two buttons. When clicked they move a div up and down:

When the button is clicked div moves down, I want to set up a max value

```
$('.button_down').click(function() {
    $('.whole_car_body').animate({
      marginTop : "+=2px"
    });
});
```

When the button is clicked div moves up, I want to set up a max value

```
$('.button_up').click(function() {
    $('.whole_car_body').animate({
      marginTop : "-=2px"
    });
});
```

I want to set a max value so when is reached the margin should stop increasing/decreasing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just perfectly.

```
var maximumDivIncrease = 6;
var currentDivIncrease = 0;
$('.button_up').click(function() {
    if(currentDivIncrease < maximumDivIncrease) {
        currentDivIncrease += 2;
        $('.whole_car_body').animate({
          marginTop : "-=2px"
        });
    }
});

var minimumDivIncrease = -6;
$('.button_down').click(function() {
    if(currentDivIncrease > minimumDivIncrease) {
        currentDivIncrease -= 2;
        $('.whole_car_body').animate({
          marginTop : "+=2px"
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. A relatively simple way would be to use a variable to "count" and a variable to store the max. i.e.:

```
var maximumDivIncrease = 50;
var currentDivIncrease = 0;
$('.button_up').click(function() {
    if(currentDivIncrease < maximumDivIncrease) {
        currentDivIncrease += 2;
        $('.whole_car_body').animate({
          marginTop : "-=2px"
        });
    }
});
```

This way it will check the variable first, and if it is lower than the maximum it will increase it, otherwise it will do nothing. To do it for the down button you simply decrease the amount and add a minimum aswell.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for the up button, but I have no idea how to set it up for the down button. If a go up three clicks, when I click the down button the starting point should be that pixel. I want to be able go up and down without passing the limits, something like this {max, 0, min}.

Comment: I did it, thank you very much. You can check the code down below.

Comment: @DragiPostolovski Yep thats exactly how i meant, well done. If you found my answer to be correct could you mark it as such?